# sql query for delete

Tags: sql

```
delete  a.Employee_LastName, a.Employee_Firstname 
FROM    EMPLOYEE a JOIN DEPARTMENT b on a.Department_ID = b.Department_ID 
where b.Department_Name='Sales' 
Group by a.Employee_LastName, a.Employee_Firstname, b.Department_Name
```

can you explain what i am doing wrong?
error(in sql server 2008):Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete is for deleting whole rows.. not emptying fields (*so column names are not supported, also no grouping*)

so

```
DELETE EMPLOYEE
FROM   EMPLOYEE a JOIN DEPARTMENT b ON a.Department_ID = b.Department_ID 
WHERE  b.Department_Name = 'Sales'
```

---

If you want to edit the records then us `UPDATE`

Answer (score 1):

"Delete" should be followed by rows, not individual columns. You should do:

```
delete a 
FROM    EMPLOYEE a JOIN DEPARTMENT b on a.Department_ID = b.Department_ID 
where b.Department_Name='Sales' 
Group by a.Employee_LastName, a.Employee_Firstname, b.Department_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify columns in a delete statement. It should be `DELETE FROM <tablename>`. Also, if you want to delete using a Join, you need to specify which table you are deleting from. So, something like:

`DELETE FROM a 
FROM <tablename> a
JOIN <othertable> b    ON a.<col> = b.<col>`

Answer (score 0):

DELETE works on a row level, so SQL Server is complaining that you have specified columns.

Here's the syntax page for DELETE:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

If you're just trying to clear the values in those columns, you should use an UPDATE statement:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(v=sql.80).aspx

If you do want to delete the rows based on that JOIN and WHERE clause, you will need to write a DELETE statement with a subquery to retrieve all the rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to delete the values from the columns which is an `update` not `delete`. use the `update` query as below:

```
    update a
    set a.Employee_LastName = null,
          a.Employee_Firstname = null
    from EMPLOYEE a INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT b
    ON a.Department_ID = b.Department_ID
    where b.Department_Name='Sales'
```

This query will remove the values (set to null) from `Employee_Firstname` and `Employee_LastName`  columns for all employees in `Sales` department.

Answer (score 0):

basic syntax is 
delete from 
where condition

from table_name is where u can create any sub query also as per your requirement.